# How to ensure that related events are processed together in Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I have a use case where I need to read events from a topic in kafka and process them in Spark.
I need to process events related to same element (element identifier is specified in the event message) and which occur within a time frame together.

1. If related events are distributed across kafka partitions, then how do we read all related events together given spark's architecture of multiple executors?
2. Is it possible to enforce that all related events go to the same partition in kafka? How will this be utilized by spark structured streaming?

Answer (score 0):

1.If you want to receive data in parallel form then you should create multiple receiver using the same topic and union them by using you'r streamingContext so u can receive the data parallel.

**Points to note::**

1. The number of executors should be at least equal to the number of receivers
2. Set the number of cores per executor such that the executor has some spare
   capacity over and above what’s needed to run the receiver
3. The total number of cores must be greater than the number of receivers;
   otherwise the application will not be able to process the data it receives

I don't know about kafka much, But i done it in MQTT.

If you need to know how i done it, Let me know

**In Scala**::

```
 val streams = (0 to 3).map{i => KafkaUtils.createStream(......)}
 val uniStream = streamingContext.union(streams)
```

Comment: is this applicable to structured streaming as well?

Comment: I'm not sure about structured streaming,I think it is possible by using your own thread pool, But not sure about it

Comment: But i'm sure  about Spark Streaming.You can create multiple receivers and those receiver will launch on diff executors and receive data parallel.I think if you are looking for parallel receiving of data then this is the best way to do it